# Change from “1 Day USPS Priority Mail” to "USPS Priority Mail” - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

Modify on the shipping name from “1 Day USPS Priority Mail” and just have it say “USPS Priority Mail”
Ensure this is updated on all transactional areas (email/invoice details/etc)

how to do this update magento 2?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Override the `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method::setPrice($price)` to change the method tittle.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Model/Quote/Address/RateResult/Method.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult;

class Method extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method
{

    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        if (strpos($this->getMethodTitle(), "Priority Mail") !== false) {
            $this->setMethodTitle("USPS Priority Mail");
        }
        $this->setData('price', $this->priceCurrency->round($price));
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Delayed. Still wanted to help someone in the need.

In your local module, you need to overwrite the below Model file.

1. MyVendor/MyModule/etc/module.xml

> ```
> <sequence>
>     <module name="Magento_Usps"/>
> </sequence>
> ```

2. MyVendor/MyModule/etc/di.xml

> 

3. MyVendor/MyModule/Model/Carrier.php

> namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Model;
>
> class Carrier extends \Magento\Usps\Model\Carrier {
>
> ```
> protected function _filterServiceName($name)
> {
>     $name = (string)preg_replace(
>         ['~<[^/!][^>]+>.*</[^>]+>~sU', '~\<!--.*--\>~isU', '~<[^>]+>~is'],
>         '',
>         html_entity_decode($name)
>     );
>     $name = str_replace('*', '', $name);
>
>     /* To Remove D-Day */
>     $name = preg_replace('/\s+?\d+-day/i', '', $name);
>     return $name;
> }
> }
> ```

That's it... Happy Coding...!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (strpos($this->getMethodTitle(), "Priority Mail 2-Day") !== false) {
            $this->setMethodTitle("USPS Priority Mail 2 to 3 Days");
        }
         if (strpos($this->getMethodTitle(), "Priority Mail Express 1-Day") !== false) {
            $this->setMethodTitle("USPS Priority Mail Express 1 to 2 Days");
        }
```